# How to check if json list has a value in it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I have a field with JSON files like this:

```
"{\"names\":[\"James\",\"Bob\",\"Kate\",\"Tim\",\"Jerald\",\"Massimo\",\"Drake\",\"Ellen\"],\"country\":[\"Usa\",\"Montenegro\",\"Turkey\",\"Spain\"]}"
```

I want to get only those rows where this field in the country includes 'USA'.
So I tried to write smth like this:

```
select *
from table
where json_field :: jsonb @> '{"country":"USA"}'::jsonb  == True
```

However, my interpreter states that
 `message [ERROR: type "jsonb" does not exist]`
Maybe there is another way how to check for the value in postgres?
Also tried this

```
json_field->'country' @> '"USA"'
```

But this returns this
`message [ERROR: operator does not exist: json @> unknown`

Comment: Myabe you should leave out the spaces in `json_field :: jsonb`?  (and use `json_field::jsonb`) ?

Comment: @Luuk doesn't help. I assume that my version of posgres just doesn't have jsonb

Comment: can you try with jsonb -> ..

Comment: @VeKe still the same mistake

Comment: @Luuk I guess no

Comment: @Luuk I have 8.3.23 verison.And unfortunately, I can't update it, as it is not on my local computer

Comment: This works for me: `select * from table where json_field->'country' ?| array['Usa']`  (But that does not work on 8.3, see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html )

Comment: Maybe you can do a text search?  like: `select * from table where json_field::varchar like '%Usa%';`

Comment: @Luuk The second script works!!Thank you!

Comment: A fair warning, because if you have a name in your json like `Susan` you also get a match...   (if your database is case insensitive)

Comment: Is this a spelling problem? Your data has `"Usa"`, but your query has `"USA"`.